# Javascript print() method not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple program that stores student objects in an array and then print the students info to the webpage. I have a print method in my program which takes a parameter and access the div element and then sets elements inner html to the parameter passed to print the message. Please consider the code snippet to see where the document.write method working fine but not the print method.

```js
var student;
var message = "";


var students =
    [
      {
        name: "Alice",
        track: "IOS",
        achievements: "Bronze",
        points: 20400
      },
      
      {
        name: "Linda",
        track: "Front End Development",
        achievements: "Silver",
        points: 26000
      }
    ];

  function print( msg )
  {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = msg;
  
  }

  for( var i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    {
      student = students[i];
      
      message = "<h2> Student : " + student.name + "</h2>";
      message += "<p> Track : " + student.track + "</p>";
      message += "<p> Achievements : " + student.achievements + "</p>";
      message += "<p> points : " + student.points + "</p>";
   // print(message);
      document.write(message);
      
    }
```

```html
<div id="output">
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine you just need to respect the text currently in the div.

I added a  `+=` to the innerHtml call to append the new text

```js
var student;
var message = "";


var students =
    [
      {
        name: "Alice",
        track: "IOS",
        achievements: "Bronze",
        points: 20400
      },
      
      {
        name: "Linda",
        track: "Front End Development",
        achievements: "Silver",
        points: 26000
      }
    ];

  function print( msg )
  {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML += msg;
  
  }

  for( var i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    {
      student = students[i];
      
      message = "<h2> Student : " + student.name + "</h2>";
      message += "<p> Track : " + student.track + "</p>";
      message += "<p> Achievements : " + student.achievements + "</p>";
      message += "<p> points : " + student.points + "</p>";
    print(message);
     // document.write(message);
      
    }
```

```html
<div id="output">
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot corn3lius for your quick solution to my problem. Can you please explain how it wasn't working and how come it worked with adding +=  please.

Comment: @knight Everytime your function print was called it would get the output div and replace all `innerHTML` with the msg. `+=` basically says `innerHTML = innerHTML + msg` therfore appending the msg to the innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

It's because your print method replaces the entire `output div`. So each iteration of the loop overwrites the previous ones output.

You can change:
`output.innerHTML = msg;`
to:
`output.innerHTML += msg;`
and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your `print` method is substituting the `innerHTML` of output each time you call it.

Therefore, if you call `print` inside a loop, the only displayed result will be the last item on the loop.

If you add a + to the method, you will get what you want. You will need a method to clear the div later on, though.

```js
var student;
var message = "";


var students = [{
    name: "Alice",
    track: "IOS",
    achievements: "Bronze",
    points: 20400
  },

  {
    name: "Linda",
    track: "Front End Development",
    achievements: "Silver",
    points: 26000
  }
];

function print(msg) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML += msg;

}

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  student = students[i];

  message = "<h2> Student : " + student.name + "</h2>";
  message += "<p> Track : " + student.track + "</p>";
  message += "<p> Achievements : " + student.achievements + "</p>";
  message += "<p> points : " + student.points + "</p>";
  print(message);

}
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```